# How to set date.timezone and what is the correct place to do it

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, php7

(I'm trying to deploy an open source [php project](https://github.com/mautic/mautic) to nginx. The project itself does not matter.)

I need to set date.timezone to my local timezone because the project uses a global setting.

I found a line in my php.ini (at /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini for debian) file but because I did not want to change the global setting, I created a new ini file in the fpm/conf.d/ directory with the line:

```
date.timezone = ('Europe/Berlin')
```

This is one of the supported time zones as [documented here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php)
However when I look at my php info, the timezone reflects in both "Local Value" as well as "Master Value".

Can I have it so that only this one php project has the timezone set while the global remains at the default UTC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fpm/conf.d/` is scanned for additional `.ini` files, making it easier to separate configuration for example per module. Those are scanned for every FPM pool, i.e. it's a global configuration just like the `php.ini`.

**You can override individual settings for a single pool in your `fpm/pool.d/poolname.conf`:**

```
php_admin_value[date.timezone] = Europe/Berlin
```

---

**Shortly on PHP FPM pools** that allows using separate settings, resources & user (permissions):

1. The default pool is configured in `fpm/pool.d/www.conf` for listening a UNIX socket:

   ```
   listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
   ```

   Also notice that it runs as the user `www-data` (or `nginx`), having all its permissions.
2. Nginx `server{}` block passes PHP script to this socket for the PHP FPM pool to handle:

   ```
   location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
       # another fastcgi options
   }
   ```
3. You can run the PHP of your single project as a separated user `mautic` by creating an additional FPM pool, e.g. `fpm/pool.d/mautic.conf` for your Mautic project:

   ```
   [mautic]
   user = mautic
   group = mautic
   listen = /run/php/mautic.sock
   chdir = /var/www/mautic   # or /home/mautic etc.
   listen.owner = www-data   # or nginx(?) to let Nginx use the socket
   listen.group = www-data

   php_admin_value[date.timezone] = Europe/Berlin
   ```

   And naturally use this new `/run/php/mautic.sock` in the relevant Nginx configuration.

The [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php) starts from where you should already know the basic idea, making it a bit hard for beginners. Luckily there are [tutorials](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/serve-php-php-fpm-and-nginx/), or you could even enjoy watching a [video](https://serversforhackers.com/c/php-fpm-multiple-resource-pools).

Comment: OK, I don't know what a "pool" is in this context. Can you please give me some best practices for deployment/ point me to a web page for these php deployments?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I am lazy and simply set it in /etc/php.ini. This covers all of the php applications on the server and in most cases all of the applications on the server will be in the same TZ.

Simply open /etc/php.ini and them find the line with date.timezone and use whatever your required timezone is. For a list of possible timezones see the official [PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php%20PHP%20doc).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that is specifically about changing the timezone for a single project, leaving others unaffected. In Debian, the path is not `/etc/php.ini` but e.g. `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini`, depending on the version and whether you use CLI, FPM etc.

Comment: Having all the projects run as a single user is not lazy, but careless. One vulnerable old WordPress plugin/theme and the whole server is a cracker playground. Real lazy people like me try to do things properly from the beginning to avoid unnecessary work in the future.

Comment: Yea, I already said I found the php.ini file and DO NOT want to change the setting globally. I managed to change the setting but only globally because I used the conf.d directory.

Comment: My apologies all, I missed that in the original question and that falls upon my shoulders.

Answer (score 0):

Side note here

In the situation where your're developing using Laravel, in the `config/app.php` file you can specify timezone only of that project.